# how to calculate the median on grouped dataset?

Tags: r, median

My dataset is as following:

```
salary  number
1500-1600   110
1600-1700   180
1700-1800   320
1800-1900   460
1900-2000   850
2000-2100   250
2100-2200   130
2200-2300   70
2300-2400   20
2400-2500   10
```

How can I calculate the median of this dataset? Here's what I have tried:

```
x <- c(110, 180, 320, 460, 850, 250, 130, 70, 20, 10)
colnames <- "numbers"
rownames <- c("[1500-1600]", "(1600-1700]", "(1700-1800]", "(1800-1900]", 
              "(1900-2000]", "(2000,2100]", "(2100-2200]", "(2200-2300]",
              "(2300-2400]", "(2400-2500]")
y <- matrix(x, nrow=length(x), dimnames=list(rownames, colnames))
data.frame(y, "cumsum"=cumsum(y))

            numbers cumsum
[1500-1600]     110    110
(1600-1700]     180    290
(1700-1800]     320    610
(1800-1900]     460   1070
(1900-2000]     850   1920
(2000,2100]     250   2170
(2100-2200]     130   2300
(2200-2300]      70   2370
(2300-2400]      20   2390
(2400-2500]      10   2400
```

Here, you can see the half-way frequency is `2400/2`=`1200`. It is between `1070` and `1920`. Thus the **median class** is the `(1900-2000]` group. You can use the formula below to get this result:

> Median = L + h/f (n/2 - c)

where:

> **L** is the lower class boundary of median class
> **h** is the size of the median class i.e. difference between upper and lower class boundaries of median class
> **f** is the frequency of median class
> **c** is previous cumulative frequency of the median class
> **n/2** is total no. of observations divided by 2 (i.e. sum **f** / 2)

Alternatively, **median class** is defined by the following method:

> Locate n/2 in the column of cumulative frequency.
>
> Get the class in which this lies.

And in code:

```
> 1900 + (1200 - 1070) / (1920 - 1070) * (2000 - 1900)    
[1] 1915.294
```

Now what I want to do is to make the above expression more elegant - i.e. `1900+(1200-1070)/(1920-1070)*(2000-1900)`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What have you tried? Have you considered providing a reproducible example? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you already know the formula, it should be easy enough to create a function to do the calculation for you.

Here, I've created a basic function to get you started. The function takes four arguments:

- `frequencies`: A vector of frequencies ("number" in your first example)
- `intervals`: A 2-row `matrix` with the same number of columns as the length of frequencies, with the first row being the lower class boundary, and the second row being the upper class boundary. Alternatively, "`intervals`" may be a column in your `data.frame`, and you may specify `sep` (and possibly, `trim`) to have the function automatically create the required matrix for you.
- `sep`: The separator character in your "`intervals`" column in your `data.frame`.
- `trim`: A regular expression of characters that need to be removed before trying to coerce to a numeric matrix. One pattern is built into the function: `trim = "cut"`. This sets the regular expression pattern to remove (, ), [, and ] from the input.

Here's the function (with comments showing how I used your instructions to put it together):

```
GroupedMedian <- function(frequencies, intervals, sep = NULL, trim = NULL) {
  # If "sep" is specified, the function will try to create the 
  #   required "intervals" matrix. "trim" removes any unwanted 
  #   characters before attempting to convert the ranges to numeric.
  if (!is.null(sep)) {
    if (is.null(trim)) pattern <- ""
    else if (trim == "cut") pattern <- "\\[|\\]|\\(|\\)"
    else pattern <- trim
    intervals <- sapply(strsplit(gsub(pattern, "", intervals), sep), as.numeric)
  }

  Midpoints <- rowMeans(intervals)
  cf <- cumsum(frequencies)
  Midrow <- findInterval(max(cf)/2, cf) + 1
  L <- intervals[1, Midrow]      # lower class boundary of median class
  h <- diff(intervals[, Midrow]) # size of median class
  f <- frequencies[Midrow]       # frequency of median class
  cf2 <- cf[Midrow - 1]          # cumulative frequency class before median class
  n_2 <- max(cf)/2               # total observations divided by 2

  unname(L + (n_2 - cf2)/f * h)
}
```

---

Here's a sample `data.frame` to work with:

```
mydf <- structure(list(salary = c("1500-1600", "1600-1700", "1700-1800", 
    "1800-1900", "1900-2000", "2000-2100", "2100-2200", "2200-2300", 
    "2300-2400", "2400-2500"), number = c(110L, 180L, 320L, 460L, 
    850L, 250L, 130L, 70L, 20L, 10L)), .Names = c("salary", "number"), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
mydf
#       salary number
# 1  1500-1600    110
# 2  1600-1700    180
# 3  1700-1800    320
# 4  1800-1900    460
# 5  1900-2000    850
# 6  2000-2100    250
# 7  2100-2200    130
# 8  2200-2300     70
# 9  2300-2400     20
# 10 2400-2500     10
```

---

Now, we can simply do:

```
GroupedMedian(mydf$number, mydf$salary, sep = "-")
# [1] 1915.294
```

---

Here's an example of the function in action on some made up data:

```
set.seed(1)
x <- sample(100, 100, replace = TRUE)
y <- data.frame(table(cut(x, 10)))
y
#           Var1 Freq
# 1   (1.9,11.7]    8
# 2  (11.7,21.5]    8
# 3  (21.5,31.4]    8
# 4  (31.4,41.2]   15
# 5    (41.2,51]   13
# 6    (51,60.8]    5
# 7  (60.8,70.6]   11
# 8  (70.6,80.5]   15
# 9  (80.5,90.3]   11
# 10  (90.3,100]    6

### Here's GroupedMedian's output on the grouped data.frame...
GroupedMedian(y$Freq, y$Var1, sep = ",", trim = "cut")
# [1] 49.49231

### ... and the output of median on the original vector
median(x)
# [1] 49.5
```

---

By the way, with the sample data that you provided, where I think there was a mistake in one of your ranges (all were separated by dashes except one, which was separated by a comma), since `strsplit` uses a regular expression by default to split on, you can use the function like this:

```
x<-c(110,180,320,460,850,250,130,70,20,10)
colnames<-c("numbers")
rownames<-c("[1500-1600]","(1600-1700]","(1700-1800]","(1800-1900]",
            "(1900-2000]"," (2000,2100]","(2100-2200]","(2200-2300]",
            "(2300-2400]","(2400-2500]")
y<-matrix(x,nrow=length(x),dimnames=list(rownames,colnames))
GroupedMedian(y[, "numbers"], rownames(y), sep="-|,", trim="cut")
# [1] 1915.294
```

Comment: It seems that your input data needs to be in ascending order. If they are out of order, it doesn't re-arrange it as necessary.

Answer (score 4):

I've written it like this to clearly explain how it's being worked out. A more compact version is appended.

```
library(data.table)

#constructing the dataset with the salary range split into low and high
salarydata <- data.table(
  salaries_low = 100*c(15:24),
  salaries_high = 100*c(16:25),
  numbers = c(110,180,320,460,850,250,130,70,20,10)
)

#calculating cumulative number of observations
salarydata <- salarydata[,cumnumbers := cumsum(numbers)]
salarydata
   # salaries_low salaries_high numbers cumnumbers
   # 1:         1500          1600     110        110
   # 2:         1600          1700     180        290
   # 3:         1700          1800     320        610
   # 4:         1800          1900     460       1070
   # 5:         1900          2000     850       1920
   # 6:         2000          2100     250       2170
   # 7:         2100          2200     130       2300
   # 8:         2200          2300      70       2370
   # 9:         2300          2400      20       2390
   # 10:         2400          2500      10       2400

#identifying median group
mediangroup <- salarydata[
  (cumnumbers - numbers) <= (max(cumnumbers)/2) & 
  cumnumbers >= (max(cumnumbers)/2)]
mediangroup
   # salaries_low salaries_high numbers cumnumbers
   # 1:         1900          2000     850       1920

#creating the variables needed to calculate median
mediangroup[,l := salaries_low]
mediangroup[,h := salaries_high - salaries_low]
mediangroup[,f := numbers]
mediangroup[,c := cumnumbers- numbers]
n = salarydata[,sum(numbers)]

#calculating median
median <- mediangroup[,l + ((h/f)*((n/2)-c))]
median
   # [1] 1915.294
```

The compact version -

EDIT: Changed to a function at @AnandaMahto's suggestion. Also, using more general variable names.

```
library(data.table)

#Creating function

CalculateMedian <- function(
   LowerBound,
   UpperBound,
   Obs
)
{
   #calculating cumulative number of observations and n
   dataset <- data.table(UpperBound, LowerBound, Obs)

   dataset <- dataset[,cumObs := cumsum(Obs)]
   n = dataset[,max(cumObs)]

   #identifying mediangroup and dynamically calculating l,h,f,c. We already have n.
   median <- dataset[
      (cumObs - Obs) <= (max(cumObs)/2) & 
      cumObs >= (max(cumObs)/2),

      LowerBound + ((UpperBound - LowerBound)/Obs) * ((n/2) - (cumObs- Obs))
   ]

   return(median)
}


# Using function
CalculateMedian(
  LowerBound = 100*c(15:24),
  UpperBound = 100*c(16:25),
  Obs = c(110,180,320,460,850,250,130,70,20,10)
)
# [1] 1915.294
```

Comment: I would *personally* like to see you convert your answer into a function as I did with my answer. Otherwise, this is not much of an addition to what the OP already knows--which is how to manually calculate the answer given the input dataset.

Answer (score 3):

```
(Sal <- sapply( strsplit(as.character(dat[[1]]), "-"), 
                                 function(x) mean( as.numeric(x) ) ) )
 [1] 1550 1650 1750 1850 1950 2050 2150 2250 2350 2450
require(Hmisc)
wtd.mean(Sal, weights = dat[[2]])
[1] 1898.75
wtd.quantile(Sal, weights=dat[[2]], probs=0.5)
```

Generalization to a weighed median might require looking for a package that has such.

Comment: I assume you mean `weighted.mean`?

Comment: No, I meant weighted median. Some packages do have such a function.

Comment: I meant in your sample code. I don't know of an existing function called "`wtd.mean`" :)

Comment: Oh. Right. I always have rms/Hmisc loaded and it has both `wtd.mean` and a `wtd.quantile` function that can give a weighted-median for a quantile of 0.5.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `median` or `apply(yourobject,2,median)` if it is a `matrix` or `data.frame` ?

Answer (score 0):

What about this way?  Create vectors for each salary bracket, assuming an even spread over each band.  Then make one big vector from those vectors, and take the median.  Similar to you, but a slightly different result.  I'm not a mathematician, so the method could be incorrect.

```
dat <- matrix(c(seq(1500, 2400, 100), seq(1600, 2500, 100), c(110, 180, 320, 460, 850, 250, 130, 70, 20, 10)), ncol=3)
median(unlist(apply(dat, 1, function(x) { ((1:x[3])/x[3])*(x[2]-x[1])+x[1] })))
```

Returns 1915.353

Answer (score -3):

I think this concept should work you.

```
$salaries = array(
       array("1500","1600"),
       array("1600","1700"),
       array("1700","1800"),
       array("1800","1900"),
       array("1900","2000"),
       array("2000","2100"),
       array("2100","2200"),
       array("2200","2300"),
       array("2300","2400"),
       array("2400","2500"),
      );
 $numbers = array("110","180","320","460","850","250","130","70","20","10");
 $cumsum = array();
 $n = 0;
 $count = 0;
 foreach($numbers as $key=>$number){    
$cumsum[$key] = $number;    
$n += $number;
if($count > 0){
    $cumsum[$key] += $cumsum[$key-1];       
}
++$count;
 }

 $classIndex = 0;
 foreach($cumsum as $key=>$cum){
if($cum < ($n/2)){
 $classIndex = $key+1;
}
 }
 $classRange = $salaries[$classIndex];
 $L = $classRange[0];
 $h = (float) $classRange[1] - $classRange[0];
 $f = $numbers[$classIndex];
 $c = $numbers[$classIndex-1];

 $Median = $L + ($h/$f)*(($n/2)-$c);
 echo $Median;
```

Comment: What language is this? The OP is looking for a solution in R.

Comment: it's PHP, i guess concept is enough for a programmer.

Comment: True, but it's not always easy to translate code from one language to another, and what might be pretty efficient in one language might turn out to be incredibly slow in another.