# how to calculate medians for unsorted dataset

Tags: r, median

I have thousands of dataset like this:

```
>student1
    quantities score
[1]          4    10         
[2]          1    12         
[3]         78     5         
[4]          6   294
```

I'd like to calculate the median of scores for this student. For every score, we have some quantities. In this case, I want it to return 5 since the median is one of the 78 5s.

I've looked at some posts here like [how to calculate the median on grouped dataset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18887382/how-to-calculate-the-median-on-grouped-dataset) , but I can't use that because I have thousands of dataset.

I've also tried to install aroma.light package and matrixstats package but still, I can't use the "weighted.median function" thing. It tells me

```
Error: could not find function "weightedMedians"
```

ok, above is just an example, my real dataset is like:

```
>test
     [,1]          [,2]
info    3            10
info    2            20
        4      86779637
        1        135777
        7          2342
```

but when I tried to use

```
>rep(test[, 1], test[, 2])
```

it appears

```
Error in rep(test[, 1], test[, 2]) : invalid 'times' argument
In addition: Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion
```

what can I do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use:

```
median(rep(student1$score, student1$quantities))
```

This is relatively fast (takes only a few seconds with a simulated dataset of 100k rows)

Comment: it told me `invalid 'times' argument` ?

Comment: Well,  probably something wrong with the quantities column. Impossible to tell without seeing the actual data...

Answer (score 0):

The function for calculating the *weighted* median in the [matrixStats](http://cran.r-project.org/package=matrixStats) package is called `weightedMedian()` (without a plural 's'), e.g.

```
> library("matrixStats")
matrixStats v0.14.0 (2015-02-13) successfully loaded. See ?matrixStats for help.
> weightedMedian(student1$score, w=student1$quantities)
[1] 5.670732
> weightedMedian(student1$score, w=student1$quantities, interpolate=FALSE)
[1] 5
```