# How to apply a custom function over each column of a matrix?

Tags: r, apply

I have been trying use a [custom function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18887382/how-to-calculate-the-median-on-grouped-dataset) that I found on here to recalculate median household income from census tracts aggregated to neighborhoods. My data looks like this

```
> inc_df[, 1:5]
          San Francisco Bayview Hunters Point Bernal Heights Castro/Upper Market Chinatown
2500-9999             22457                  1057            287                 329      1059
10000-14999           20708                   920            288                 463      1327
1500-19999            12701                   626            145                 148       867
20000-24999           12106                   491            285                 160       689
25000-29999           10129                   554            238                 328       167
30000-34999           10310                   338            257                 179       289
35000-39999            9028                   383            184                 163       326
40000-44999            9532                   472            334                 173       264
45000-49999            8406                   394            345                 241       193
50000-59999           17317                   727            367                 353       251
60000-74999           25947                  1037            674                 794       236
75000-99999           36378                  1185            980                 954       289
100000-124999         33890                   990            640                1208       199
125000-149999         24935                   522            666                 957       234
150000-199999         37190                   814           1310                1535       150
200000-250001         65763                   796           2122                3175       302
```

The function is as follows:

```
GroupedMedian <- function(frequencies, intervals, sep = NULL, trim = NULL) {
  # If "sep" is specified, the function will try to create the 
  #   required "intervals" matrix. "trim" removes any unwanted 
  #   characters before attempting to convert the ranges to numeric.
  if (!is.null(sep)) {
    if (is.null(trim)) pattern <- ""
    else if (trim == "cut") pattern <- "\\[|\\]|\\(|\\)"
    else pattern <- trim
    intervals <- sapply(strsplit(gsub(pattern, "", intervals), sep), as.numeric)
  }

  Midpoints <- rowMeans(intervals)
  cf <- cumsum(frequencies)
  Midrow <- findInterval(max(cf)/2, cf) + 1
  L <- intervals[1, Midrow]      # lower class boundary of median class
  h <- diff(intervals[, Midrow]) # size of median class
  f <- frequencies[Midrow]       # frequency of median class
  cf2 <- cf[Midrow - 1]          # cumulative frequency class before median class
  n_2 <- max(cf)/2               # total observations divided by 2

  unname(L + (n_2 - cf2)/f * h)
}
```

And the code to apply the function looks like this:

```
GroupedMedian(inc_df[, "Bernal Heights"], rownames(inc_df), sep="-", trim="cut")
```

This all works fine but I can't figure out how to apply this to each column of the matrix instead of typing out each column name and running it again and again. I have tried this:

```
> minc_hood <- data.frame(apply(inc_df, 2, function(x) GroupedMedian(inc_df[, x], 
rownames(inc_df), sep="-", trim="cut")))
```

But I get this error message

```
Error in inc_df[, x] : subscript out of bounds
```

Comment: Change `inc_df[, x]` to just `x`. Also, maybe you should apply it to `inc_df[,-1]` because I don't think it will work on the first column.

Comment: Changing it to just x worked like a charm - thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There are a couple of things at play here:

- advice: never use `apply` with a `data.frame` (unless you are absolutely certain you don't mind the overhead of converting to `matrix`^1 and can accept the potential data loss^2).
- even if you're going to use `apply`, you're doing it a little "off": when you say `apply(df, 2, func)`, it takes the first column of `df` and presents it as the arguments, so for instance

  ```
  apply(mtcars, 2, mean)
  ```

  will make calls like

  ```
  mean(c(21, 21, 22.8, 21.4, 18.7, ...)) # mpg
  mean(c(6, 6, 4, 6, 8, ...))            # cyl
  mean(c(160, 160, 108, 258, 360, ...))  # disp
  # ... etc
  ```

  In that context, your use of `apply(inc_df, 2, function(x) GroupedMedian(inc_df[, x], ...))` is wrong, since `x` is replaced by all values of the first column of `inc_df` (and then all values of the 2nd column, etc).

Since your function looks like it accepts a vector of values (plus some other arguments), I suggest you try something like

```
inc_df[] <- lapply(inc_df, GroupedMedian, rownames(inc_df), sep="-", trim="cut")
```

If you want to apply this function to a *subset* of those columns, then something like this works well:

```
ind <- c(1,3,7)
inc_df[ind] <- lapply(inc_df[ind], GroupedMedian, rownames(inc_df), sep="-", trim="cut")
```

The use of `inc_df[] <- ...` (when not doing a column-subset) ensures that we replace the values of the columns without losing the attribute that it is a `data.frame`. It is effectively the same as `inc_df <- as.data.frame(...)` with some other minor nuances.

Notes:

^1: `apply` will always convert a `data.frame` to a `matrix`. This might be alright, but with larger data will take a non-zero amount of time. It also may have consequences, see next ...

^2: a `matrix` can have only one class, unlike a `data.frame`. That means that all columns will be up-converted to the highest common type, in the order of `logical < integer < numeric < POSIXct < character`. This means that if you have all `numeric` columns and one `character`, then the function you are `apply`ing on it will see all `character` data. This can be mitigated by only selecting those columns with the types you expect, perhaps with:

```
isnum <- sapply(inc_df, is.numeric)
inc_df[isnum] <- apply(inc_df[isnum], 2, GroupedMedian, ...)
```

and in that case, the worst conversion you will get will be `integer`-to-`numeric`, likely an acceptable (and reversible) conversion.